# How to make Docker reuse common dotnet dlls?

Tags: .net, docker

**Our situation:**

We're creating a microservice based application, consisting of many .NET docker containers (ASP.NET Core), which of course all have a very large common set of dlls, about 8 MB in size.

Problem is that the base layers are shared and cached on the client devices, of course, but we want to squeeze more efficiency out of it (because 1000 clients x 20 services x 8 MB is still 160 GB of download of which most can be avoided!).

**What I've tried so far:**

1. I created a dockerfile for the services which does something like:

```
copy --from xyz.example.com/common-libraries /app /app

copy /publish /app
```

2. Tried using this to build the docker containers
3. Result is now that I download the 8 MB layer from "common-libraries" but then again all the 8 MB from the actual build, even though the files are the same (even checked with sha256sum and ls -l, all is identical)
4. Also tried `COPY --link --from... etc...` for good measure, but this only tells me that "LLB doesn't know anything about --link"

**Our request for help:**

Is there any way we can create an extra layer for the many, some of them large, dll files for a dotnet docker container? This would be great for the environment as well, because we all know that large downloads also create CO2 pressure.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom image to use as the base for your images. If you create a Dockerfile like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
copy --from xyz.example.com/common-libraries /app /app
```

Then build that using

```
docker build -t custom-aspnet:6.0 .
```

Then use it as the base for your other images by having

```
FROM custom-aspnet:6.0
```

in them, instead of `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0`.

You should also push the base image to your image repository for other developers to use.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem, either... that was my first approach a few months ago, but the layers are still both around 8 MB in that case.

Comment: Yes. But you only download the new base image once.